# How to replace if null for lambda

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, refactoring

How should I use lambda expression to get the same result as 'if else' below:

```
List<String> list = List.of("a", "b");

if (list == null) {
    return null;
} else {
    return StringUtils.join(list, ",");
}
```

On start I have to check if list is different than null, so:

```
Optional.ofNullable(list)...
```

and now I do not know what I should do next

Comment: The best way to do deal with this is to make sure the List is never null in the first place.  null is a poison value that should never occur in code under normal circumstances.  null definitely should never be used as a synonym for an empty collection, array, or Map.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and [`.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)):

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(list).map(l -> StringUtils.join(l, ",")).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works, but I have another one question - How to modify this when list will be as field of Object? Object object = new Object(List<String> list) and I would like to check if that objct is not null on start?

Comment: @OptimusPrime98 You could throw an exception by using `Objects.requireNonNull` in the constructor of your class.

Comment: I think using the original code with the if is preferable over using `Optional` here (it is simpler and easier to understand, and likely more performant).